# Counting the number of words in a Column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by, count

How do you group this data, based on Patterns? Is it possible in SQL?

```
 CREATE TABLE ABC ("NAMES" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)) `

`INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('CA Apple 3');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('New Apple 4');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Cra Apple 5');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('UK Apple 5c');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Apple 6s');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Apple 7');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Apple x');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('az Apple xr');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Apple xs');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Motorola RIZR');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('eu Motorola RAZR');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Motorola RoZR');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Motorola RR');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('fin Motorola RIZ');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Motorola R');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('sau Google Pixel');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Google Pixel 2');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Google Pixel 3');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Samsung Galaxy');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('aus Samsung Galaxy 3');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Samsung Small 2');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Samsung Earth');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('ko Samsung Solar');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Samsung Milky Way');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Samsung Chill');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Yi Apple Chill');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('In Apple');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('razy Motorola');
 INSERT INTO ABC (names) VALUES ('Samsung');`
```

So, I have a table like this, Imagine there is 500000 rows and 4800 brand names.

The 4800 brand names can either be the first word, second word, third word or last word.

> One possible way to solve this would be to get the substrings and count them, and Order by count(pattern) desc where rownum < 4800;

Now I need to find the count of the words (Eg: Apple, Samsung, Motorola)

Desired output is shown below:

[image]

Comment: What dbms is it? You tagged `sql-Server ` and `Oracle`

Comment: I would like to know the syntax for either sql-server or oracle. Because I use both softwares. I have the table to upload it to either.

Comment: SQL Server does not have `varchar2()` so I voted for Oracle and removed the SQL Server tag.

Comment: Is there a way to delete the question, I solved this in R  `table(unlist(strsplit(tolower(abc$names), " ")))`  because the application is not letting me post SQL questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this data set is below:

```
`select * from(
 select x,count(*) as coun from ( 
 select substr(names,
            INSTR(names, ' ', -1, 1)+1) as x
            from abc


  union all

  SELECT SUBSTR(names,
          INSTR(names, ' ', 1, 1) + 1,
          INSTR(names, ' ', 1, 2) - INSTR(names, ' ', 1, 1) - 1) as x
  FROM abc

  union all 

   SELECT SUBSTR(names,1,
          INSTR(names, ' ',1 , 1)-1) as x
   FROM abc
   )
   where x is not null and x not in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')
  group by x
  order by coun desc)
  where rownum < 4800;'
```

Answer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern can be simplified to the 1st word of the name, then something like this:

```
select
  case 
    when names like '%_ %' then substring(names, 1, charindex(' ', names) - 1) 
    else names
  end pattern,
  count(*) counter
from abc
group by case 
    when names like '%_ %' then substring(names, 1, charindex(' ', names) - 1) 
    else names
  end
```

which will work for SqlServer.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8b0445127361ccf2b2f9956099a86ee8).
Results:

```
> pattern  | counter
> :------- | ------:
> Apple    |       9
> Google   |       3
> In       |       1
> Motorola |       6
> razy     |       1
> Samsung  |       8
> Yi       |       1
```

Comment: I do not have MySql on my system but, Does it work if the keyword is the second or last word?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55820173/pattern-grouping-in-sql?noredirect=1#comment98307083_55820173 I like your idea, But, Apple count is 11. I think another statement should be added.

Comment: As I said it works only if the pattern is the 1st word as the code cannot *guess* which part of the value is the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have keywords that you want to find, you can do a `join` like this:

```
select p.pat, count(*) 
from abc join
     (select 'Motorola' as pat from dual union all
      select 'Samsung' from dual union all
      select 'Apple' from dual union all
      . . .
     ) p
     on abc.name like '%' || p.pat || '%'
group by p.pat
order by count(*) desc;
```

Note that this will count a single row more than one time if it matches more than one pattern.

Comment: @StackOne . . . You would have to define the rules for finding the "patterns" and explain what these are in your question.

Answer (score 1):

In `SQL-Server` starting version 2008 you can [create a fulltext index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on your desired column. This assumes you have an index column on your table. 
Example:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uix_abc_id ON ABC(id);
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft AS DEFAULT;  
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON ABC(names)   
   KEY INDEX uix_abc_id   
   WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM;
```

This will allow you to efficiently query occurrences count for words using the `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords` stored procedure.

[image: example]

Typically, common keywords are declared as stopwords and you can [add your own stopwords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-stopwords-and-stoplists-for-full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017), which won’t be indexed and won’t appear in the mentioned stored proc.